# I am not able to debug Home sample application in android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to debug the Home Sample application(To change the theme of home) provided in android sdk. but I am not able to do so.
No error is shown but no breakpoints are encountered either.I am confused.Can somebody suggest something?

Comment: Do you have `android:debuggable="true"` in the android manifest?

Comment: I have set android:debuggable="true" and I have marked a breakpoint on setcontentlayout(home.xml) in home.java file and debug the application as android application but no debugging occurs and the application executes successfully

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Launching the Home sample using *Debug As > Android Application* in Eclipse doesn't attach the debugger to the process automatically. Probably because an Home Screen is not shown right away like a normal Android application.

However you can manually attach the Eclipse debugger to the *com.example.android.home* process by selecting it from the *Devices* view and clicking on the debug button.

If you don't see the Devices view in Eclipse use: *Window > Show View > Others... > Android > Devices*

[image]

Comment: Thanks ... I did this..Its debugging but still My purpose of breakpoints control is not solved.

Comment: If you have gone through the Home application, can u explain me the purpose of XMLPullParser used in bindFavorites () method in Home.java file?   Thanks in advance

Comment: It is used to parse the contents of `/system/etc/favorites.xml` which describes a collection of favorites apps to stick at the bottom of the screen. The format of that file is: `<favorites><favorite package="com.android.email" class="com.android.email.activity.Welcome"/></favorites>`. You can't write to `/system/etc` on a normal device however you could change the path to something else in the code if you wish to try this feature.

Comment: Thanx for the reply..But I have another question...I tried changing the icon of apps with same icon for all app ..I did it but the list of favs and recents does not show the changed icons..Why is that so?

Comment: The approach that Alexandre suggests works - I needed to debug my app which doesn't have a launcher! However, Android throws up an invisible layer which prevents click events from reaching the target app (to trigger my app) - to overcome this I have to press the Back button first !

Answer (score 1):

You could change the category in the intent filter to LAUNCHER so that the application comes up in the default launcher. Then you should be able to debug it with breakpoints like any other normal application.

Change to this in the manifest file

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>`

instead of the existing

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>"`